# Accessing a class constant using a simple variable which contains the name of the constant

Tags: php, class, variables, constants

I'm trying to access a class constant in one of my classes:

```
const MY_CONST = "value";
```

If I have a variable which holds the name of this constant like this:

```
$myVar = "MY_CONST";
```

Can I access the value of MY_CONST somehow?

```
self::$myVar
```

This is not working obviously because it is for static properties.
Also, Variable variables does not work either.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

There are two ways to do this: using the [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function or using [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

### Constant Function

The constant function works with constants declared through `define` as well as class constants:

```
class A
{
    const MY_CONST = 'myval';

    static function test()
    {
        $c = 'MY_CONST';
        return constant('self::'. $c);
    }
}

echo A::test(); // output: myval
```

### Reflection Class

A second, more laborious way, would be through reflection:

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass('A');
$constName = 'MY_CONST';
echo $ref->getConstant($constName); // output: myval
```

Comment: And how to solve this problem if I have a Trait with my constant and a class implementing this Trait?

Answer (score 38):

There is no syntax for that, but you can use an explicit lookup:

```
print constant("classname::$myConst");
```

I believe it also works with `self::`.

Comment: Using "print" confused me for a second because that's not really part of the solution, but yeah, using the `constant()` function seems to be the best way to do this.

Comment: It look like is necessary to specify the class namespace if the class is on a different path.

Comment: warning, this doesn't work with namespaces, but my solution does: https://3v4l.org/uOOHp

Answer (score 3):

> Can I access the value of MY_CONST somehow?

```
self::MY_CONST
```

If you want to access is dynamically, you can use the [reflection API <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
$myvar = 'MY_CONST';
$class = new ReflectionClass(self);
$const = $class->getConstant($myVar);
```

The benefit with the reflection API can be that you can get all constants at once (`getConstants`).

If you dislike the reflection API because you don't wanna use it, an alternative is the `constant` function ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0DORea)):

```
$myvar = 'MY_CONST';    
class foo {const MY_CONST = 'bar';}    
define('self', 'foo');    
echo constant(self.'::'.$myvar);
```

Comment: I don't want to use reflection for this.

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve the same, checkout http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php - works on class constants as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note for Reflection: the constructor for ReflectionClass must receive the **full path** of the class for its parameter. 
This means that just setting the string 'A' as a constructor parameter may not work in some cases.

To avoid this problem, when using ReflectionClass you will be better if you do this:

```
$classA = new A();
$name_classA = get_class($classA);
$ref = new ReflectionClass(get_class($name_classA));
$constName = 'MY_CONST';
echo $ref->getConstant($constName);
```

Function get_class will give you the full path of a class whenever you are in the code. Missing the full path may result in a "Class not found" PHP error.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$myVar = MY_CONST or $myVar = $MY_CONST
```

Comment: I don't know which constant I will be accessing. The name of a constant is evaluated at runtime and put into $myVar. So this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this solution is slightly better than the existing ones:

```php
class C {
   public const WUT=5;
}
$v = "WUT";
var_dump(constant(C::class . "::$v"));
=> int(5)
```

- mario's solution comes close, but doesn't work with namespaces, while my solution /does/ work with namespaces: https://3v4l.org/SUYbi
- for `self` use `constant(self::class . "::$v");`