# php late static bindings: return static::CONST using reflection

Tags: php, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing a class constant using a simple variable which contains the name of the constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506530/accessing-a-class-constant-using-a-simple-variable-which-contains-the-name-of-th)

I would like to use reflection to send an array of const as a result of a static call

```
class ArrowType extends AbstractAttributeType
{
    const NORMAL = 'normal';
    const INV = 'inv';

    static function getPossibleValues()
    {
        $refl = new \ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
        $class_vars = $refl->getConstants();
        $res = array();
        foreach ($class_vars as $name => $value) {
            $res[] = static::$$name;
        }

        return $res;
    }
}
```

this gives me

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: **ArrowType::$NORMAL**

I would like to get

> *ArrowType::NORMAL*

When calling *$arrowType->getPossibleValues()*

**EDIT**

In order to make my question a little more understable, I will give you the details.
I am using the https://github.com/yethee/BiplaneEnumBundle and I am trying to make my life easier. For the moment, I have to produce the code below in order to follow the library requirements.

```
class ArrowType extends AbstractAttributeType
{
    const NORMAL = 'normal';
    const INV = 'inv';
    const DOT = 'dot';
    const INVDOT = 'invdot';
    const ODOT = 'odot';
    const INVODOT = 'invodot';
    const NONE = 'none';

    static function getPossibleValues()
    {
        return array(
                    static::NORMAL,
                    static::INV,
                    static::DOT,
                    static::INVDOT,
                    static::ODOT,
                    static::INVODOT,
                    static::NONE
                    );
    }

    static function getReadables()
    {
        return array(
                    static::NORMAL => 'normal',
                    static::INV => 'inv',
                    static::DOT => 'dot',
                    static::INVDOT => 'invdot',
                    static::ODOT => 'odot',
                    static::INVODOT => 'invodot',
                    static::NONE => 'none'
                );
    }

}
```

what I am trying to achieve now, is to build dynamically the array in the two functions in order to put these functions in a parent class and just declare in my classes the const part. I hope that helps the kind reader understand what I want.

Comment: While that's ultimately the solution, I'm not sure it's close enough to be a dupe.

Comment: Sure, let's also take into account that the question answers itself: `$res[] = $value;` *or* `$res = array_values($refl->getConstants());` - when using reflection, it's all already there.

Comment: Ahaha, I just realized that.

Comment: Yeah this question is not really clear. Maybe Mylen can shed some light what the actual problem is?

Comment: What's really funny (ah ah) it's that my post as been tampered with, the title as been changed! My question was about lazy static binding!
and it may not be clear enough for you but il you execute the code above, you get an error, what I want is explained in blockquote in the last paragraph

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I forgot the return statement in my method, it may be usefull to understand what I wanted to do though the method name was quite explicit...

Comment: @Mylen, except that it isn't about LSB *at all*.  The only time LSB comes into play is when you create the ReflectionClass object, which is what you're actually using to extract the constants, and then it's only present by accident.

Comment: Charles, do you mind to take a 2mn chat so we can explain each other? I start to get confuse with all of this

Comment: @Charles, sorry I did not understand the php doc then, I though that late binding was use when **calling static::**

Comment: @Mylen, you're suffering from a variant on [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135887). The question you asked is "how do I use feature Y to get to X," while in reality, the question you're actually asking is "how do I get to X".  LSB has only come into play because you thought you needed to take a roundabout route.  In reality, you already stumbled upon the solution and didn't realize it.  Anyway, this is getting kinda meta.  I'm not going to be able to join you in chat, as I need to be awake in five hours.  Ick.

Comment: Ok @Charles, may be another time, It's 11am where I live, go get some rest and thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Wait, wait, hold on a moment.

```
    $class_vars = $refl->getConstants();
    $res = array();
    foreach ($class_vars as $name => $value) {
        ...
```

You *already* have the value.  It's right there.  You don't even need the foreach.  Just `return $refl->getConstants()`

Comment: You may ask yourself why I would loose 10 minutes asking for a question if I already have the answer.. I do not really like the way stackoverflow allow people to modify your post without asking the author first...

Comment: @Mylen, please refer to the [site FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing).  Collaborative editing is a core feature.