# Get constant value using variable name

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a class like bellow,

```
 namespace DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
 class SiteIds
{
    // United States
    const US = 0;
    // Canada (English)
    const ENCA = 2;
    // UK
    const GB = 3;
    // Australia
    const AU = 15;
    // Austria
    const AT = 16;
    // Belgium (French)
    const FRBE = 23;
    // France
    const FR = 71;
    // Germany
    const DE = 77;
    // Motors
    const MOTORS = 100;
    // Italy
    const IT = 101;
    // Belgium (Dutch)
    const NLBE = 123;
    // Netherlands
    const NL = 146;
    // Spain
    const ES = 186;
    // Switzerland
    const CH = 193;
    // Hong Kong
    const HK = 201;
    // India
    const IN = 203;
    // Ireland
    const IE = 205;
    // Malaysia
    const MY = 207;
    // Canada (French)
    const FRCA = 210;
    // Philippones
    const PH = 211;
    // Poland
    const PL = 212;
    // Singapore
    const SG = 216;
}
```

I can access this like as follows,

```
echo Constants\SiteIds::US;
```

But when i try to access this like bellow ,It is not working,

```
  $country ='US';
  echo Constants\SiteIds::$country;
```

Is there any method to access like this?

Comment: You should check this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506530/accessing-a-class-constant-using-a-simple-variable-which-contains-the-name-of-th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass('DTS\eBaySDK\Constants\SiteIds');
$constName = 'US';
echo $ref->getConstant($constName);
```

I found this answer at : [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506530/accessing-a-class-constant-using-a-simple-variable-which-contains-the-name-of-th)

Answer (score 0):

To get a constant using a variable you have to use the [`constant`](http://php.net/constant) function. That function requires the *fully qualified name* of the constant, which in your case includes the namespace:

```
constant("DTS\eBaySDK\Constants\SiteIds::$country")
```

Or from within the same namespace:

```
constant(__NAMESPACE__ . "\SiteIds::$country")
```