# php class constant call $this::CONST

Tags: php, oop, constants

Why I can call class constant from dynamic declaration? 
This code works well:

```
echo $this::CONST;
```

Isn't it wrong?

Comment: why it is wrong ? constant can be access in many ways. It is one of them . see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506530/accessing-a-class-constant-using-a-simple-variable-which-contains-the-name-of-th

Comment: you are mixing up constants with private variables as it seems

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    const CONSTANT = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::CONSTANT . "\n";
    }
}

echo MyClass::CONSTANT . "\n";

$classname = "MyClass";
echo $classname::CONSTANT . "\n"; // As of PHP 5.3.0

$class = new MyClass();
$class->showConstant();

echo $class::CONSTANT."\n"; // As of PHP 5.3.0
?>
```

Calling a constant from a dynamic declaration works just as well as calling it from the class

Comment: I know it)) But calling constant from dynamic 
environmentis really right?)

Comment: A constant is just a value that won't change inside the class declaration, therefore every instance of that class will have that constant with it's value. There is no problem with calling it from the instance :)

Comment: not the problem. The problem in the code design. I found $this::CONST in one developer's code and smiled)) I think, this is ugly)
because I used to design code like in manuals, but not the way I like it