# PHP access dynamic attribute from constant content

Tags: php, oop, variables, dynamic, constants

I want to access a dynamics attribute with the name of the content of a constant. Like `constant($var)` just the other way around.

This is working, but I am wondering is there is something simpler (without `$varname`)?

```
const CONST_1  = 'var_1';
$this->var_1 = 'Hello World';

$varnam = CONST_1;
echo $this->$varnam;
```

Comment: The context is unclear ... For what I can see, you code doesn't work you way you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a class constant using a simple variable which contains the name of the constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506530/accessing-a-class-constant-using-a-simple-variable-which-contains-the-name-of-th)

Comment: sry for the missing context, but your answer was what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside my initial comment :

You can do

```
echo $this->{CONST_1}
```

if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
<?php
const CONST_1  = 'var_1';
$var_1 = 'Hello World';

echo ${CONST_1};
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a42f8241e286399618599b54b97929200d6b1923