# Dynamically accessing static properties using variable

Tags: php, oop, variables, static

I'm trying to dynamically access a static namespaced property (using delight-im's `auth`). Possible values could be:

```
\Delight\Auth\Role::ADMIN
\Delight\Auth\Role::USER
```

etc

I want to name the `ADMIN` part dynamically, as such:

```
\Delight\Auth\Role::$role
```

But PHP is telling me:

```
 Access to undeclared static property: Delight\Auth\Role::$role
```

So I tried to use a variable variable as such:

```
 \Delight\Auth\Role::$$val
```

(two `$`s) and the error changes to:

```
 Access to undeclared static property: Delight\Auth\Role::$ADMIN
```

So as you can see the variable is resolved, but there is a `$` inserted in there still. I'm using PHP `5.6.37` if that makes a difference.

Is there a way to access static properties dynamically like this?

Comment: are `ADMIN` and `USER` constants? if yes, read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506530/accessing-a-class-constant-using-a-simple-variable-which-contains-the-name-of-th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up your terminology. The syntax you're using is accessing a class's static property, but you're describing features of a class constant.

[Static properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties) are *mutatable* variables stored on the class. Example from the PHP manual:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public static $my_static = 'foo';

    public function staticValue() {
        return self::$my_static;
    }
}
```

You'd reference $my_static like this: `Foo::$my_static`, which is what you're doing.

[*Class constants*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) seems to be what you're describing. Example from the PHP manual:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    const CONSTANT = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::CONSTANT . "\n";
    }
}
```

You'd reference CONSTANT like this: `MyClass::CONSTANT`.

Here's a [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506530/accessing-a-class-constant-using-a-simple-variable-which-contains-the-name-of-th) describing how to reference class constants dynamically, which is what you're attempting to do.