# php Using variable in an call

Tags: php, api

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property:
>   DTS\eBaySDK\Constants\GlobalIds::$stripped in
>   /home/jimi13/public_html/dealpopup.com/ebayapi/finding/mine.php on
>   line 334

```
$stripped = str_replace(' ', '', $country);
$stripped = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $stripped);
echo $stripped;
```

need to take put stripped into this

```
$service = new Services\FindingService([
    'credentials' => $config['production']['credentials'],
    'globalId'    => Constants\GlobalIds::US
]);
```

need to put this in, but throws error

```
$service = new Services\FindingService([
    'credentials' => $config['production']['credentials'],
    'globalId'    => Constants\GlobalIds::$stripped
]);
```

Comment: Think it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506530/accessing-a-class-constant-using-a-simple-variable-which-contains-the-name-of-th

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have not yet been able to send what I need.

I am trying to send the variable $stripped in place of the US. 

How would I achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can access a constant variable in the class with namespace. If no namespace then you can remove the Constants namespace.

```
namespace Constants;

class Hello {
  const WORLD = 'Hello World';
}

$world = 'WORLD';
echo constant('Constants\Hello::' . $world);
```