# How to call a constant inside a class dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, constants, entity

Here is the code inside App\Entity\User.php:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use ...

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{

    const USER_ROLE = 'user';
    const ADMIN_ROLE = 'admin';

    // ...

    public function getRole(string $roleConstant): ?string
    {
        return self::$roleConstant ?? null;
    }
}
```

The goal of the `getRole()` method is to return a constant dynamically.

**This getter is a bit special as it takes a parameter.**  That is why i don't use the common static syntax `self::USER_ROLE`. As the constant must be dynamical, i tried to use this one instead: `self::$roleConstant`

But this is not working. While running the above code, i get this error message: `Undefined property '$roleConstant'.intelephense(1014)`

*I am using **Symfony 5**. But the error is not related to Symfony. It's more a general PHP syntax issue i think.*

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, it's a special getter as it takes a parameter. I'm not sure if this is a correct practice. I'm editing the question to precise this point.

Comment: PHP has a constant function for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506530/accessing-a-class-constant-using-a-simple-variable-which-contains-the-name-of-th

Comment: Oh wow thank you very much, that's perfect. I didn't manage to find this post.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the constant() function.

```
 public function getRole(string $roleConstant): ?string
 {
     return constant('self::' . $roleConstant);
 }
```

As precised in this post: [Accessing a class constant using a simple variable which contains the name of the constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506530/accessing-a-class-constant-using-a-simple-variable-which-contains-the-name-of-th)

Thank you @Cerad for your comment.

Comment: There is no real need for this sort of answer when there is already a perfectly good answer.  Consider upvoting the linked answer and then just deleting your question/answer.