# Call enum with a variable

Tags: php, enums

I have declared a enum in PHP like:

```php
namespace App\Model\Enum;

class Reason
{
    public const ALL = [
        self::REASON,
    ];

    public const TYPE = [
        self::REASON => 'insert text',
    ];

    public const REASON = 'insert_text';
}
```

and i want to call it like this:

```php
use App\Model\Enum\Reason;

$variable = 'variable';

echo Reason::$variable;
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
Access to undeclared static property
```

Couldn't find a lot on the internet, so is it possible?

Comment: That syntax is for static properties. For constants: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506530/accessing-a-class-constant-using-a-simple-variable-which-contains-the-name-of-th

Comment: Php supports enum now.